# Why does the lenght of tuple types change on intersection?

Tags: typescript, type-systems

I have a little project to build a wrapper class for JavaScript numbers, such supports more specific types (PositveInteger, NotNegativeNumber, NotZeroNumber ...).

While coding I found this curio:
If I intersect two tuple types of the same length the result is a tuple that has more than the original entries:

```
type TupleA = [0 | 1, 0 | 1];
type TupleB = [2 | 1, 2 | 1];
type IntesectionTuple = TupleA & TupleB;
let a0: TupleA[0];
let a1: TupleA[1];
let a2: TupleA[2]; // fails like expceted

let b0: TupleB[0];
let b1: TupleB[1];
let b2: TupleB[2]; // fails like expceted

let i0: IntesectionTuple[0];
let i1: IntesectionTuple[1];
let i2: IntesectionTuple[2]; // does not fail ... why?

// the new entry has type 1
const _0: IntesectionTuple[2] extends 1 ? true : false = true;
const _1: 1 extends IntesectionTuple[2] ? true : false = true;
```

My project repo:
https://github.com/lasbec/TsHuntingUtils/tree/main/curios

Comment: I swear I've seen a question on this before, but sadly this is one of those that's super hard to search for. Note that not only is `IntesectionTuple[2]` defined, but any index following as well, the type essentially gets squashed to `1[]`.

Comment: Ah wait it’s https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42557

Comment: Thanks alot, but let me add that the resulting type is actually not the same as [1, 1, ...1[]]. But you are right that every other index of the tuple type is of type 1.